# Access value of retry counter after XAUTOCLAIM

Tags: redis

I'm using Redis streams to build a queueing feature. I want to prevent bad messages clogging the queue, so I only want to try them N times before discarding them.

I'm using the pattern:

```
Producer: XADD
Consumer: XAUTOCLAIM or XREADGROUP
Consumer: XACK
```

The consumer first tries to XAUTOCLAIM old messages from the pending list, and if none exist, it uses XREADGROUP to pick an message off the queue. It then XACKs the processed message.

The documentation for XAUTOCLAIM mentions a "retry counter", which sounds perfect for my use case. But I can't figure out how to read the retry counter for a message.

Comment: Have a look at [`XPENDING`'s "extended form"](https://redis.io/commands/xpending#extended-form-of-xpending)

Comment: Thanks Itamar, just to make sure I understand, you're referring to the 4th value of the returned tuple ("The number of times this message was delivered.")?

Comment: Yep, that's was the intended reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Itamar Haber points out in the comments, the retry counter can be accessed with the [extended form of XPENDING](https://redis.io/commands/xpending#extended-form-of-xpending). Specifically, the fourth value of the response tuple is the "number of times this message was delivered."